# How to write raw SQL with placeholder for AR SQL Server adapter?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server-2008, activerecord

I have a complicated join condition with three interpolated values that are being double-quoted (as part of AR's quoting to avoid SQL injection attacks, I think).

I've ready other questions saying that I can make use of `:sanitize_sql` or `:sanitize_sql_array` with `?` placeholders, but alas, those seem to be undefined with [`activerecord-sqlserver-adapter`](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter).

So, my question is, how can I make this work with SQL server through ActiveRecord??

---

```
def self.with_active_deal_counts
  joins(<<-SQL.squish
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT [b].[merchant_id], COUNT(*) deal_count
      FROM   [tbl_deal] b
      WHERE deal_active = 1
        AND deal_archive = 2
        AND ( deal_end = '1900-01-01'
              OR deal_end > '#{Time.now + Time.now.utc_offset - 1.day}')
        AND deal_start <= '#{Time.now + Time.now.utc_offset}'
      GROUP BY [b].[merchant_id]
    ) a ON a.[merchant_id] = [tbl_merchant].[merchant_id]
    SQL
  ).select("tbl_merchant.*, a.deal_count")
end
```

This yields

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT tbl_merchant.*, a.deal_count FROM [tbl_merchant] LEFT OUTER JOIN (
 SELECT [b].[merchant_id], COUNT(*) deal_count
 FROM [tbl_deal] b
 WHERE deal_active = 1
 AND deal_archive = 2
 AND ( deal_end = ''1900-01-01''
 OR deal_end > ''2013-09-30 07:07:20 -0700'')
 AND deal_start <= ''2013-10-01 07:07:20 -0700''
 GROUP BY [b].[merchant_id]
) a ON a.[merchant_id] = [tbl_merchant].[merchant_id]'
```

... which doesn't work because of the double-quoted values, eg. `''2013-09-30 07:07:20 -0700''`

Specifically, I get `Incorrect syntax near '1900'` (when running the query in SQL Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is specifically about placeholder which I'm unsure about.  I ran into a similar situation once and ended up using ruby "interpolated string", which might be worth to look at.

The `%Q` (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals) or for multi-line sql, heredoc could be handy.  Here is how you could use `%Q` for the sql:

```
sql = %Q[ some crazy SQL with '#{Time.now}' ]
```

An example usage would be the following:

```
sql = %Q[ select '#{Time.now}' ]
# This translates to
N' select ''2013-10-01 16:25:46 -0400'' '
=> #<ActiveRecord::Result:0x000000052acc40 @columns=[""], @rows=[["2013-10-01 16:25:46 -0400"]], @hash_rows=nil>
```

Comment: I've tried interpolation, but the output `''2013-10-01 16:25:46 -0400''` does not work: is needs to be `'2013-10-01 16:25:46 -0400'` or else SQL Server will complain.

Comment: See my updated question above--sorry, I had to type the first version on my iPhone, so it was a bit more terse than I would've liked. :)

Comment: @neezer, apologies for late response.  Could you also post how you are executing the query from Rails.